# Setting com0com friendly names

Tags: com0com

I'm working on a project including a pair of virtual comports by com0com. I need to change the friendly names from "Com0com - serial port emulator xxxxxx" to something I wrote my self. I found the `Updatefnames` command in com0com v3.0.0, but I cant find how to use it any where. I need to script the set-up.

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows specific, something similar should get you into the command shell on Linux: 
1. Open a command prompt in the i386 (32 bit) or x64 (64 bit) directory as Administrator into the folder where you downloaded com0com 
2. Run the command "setupc" you will see special command prompt "command>"
3. Type "list" press Enter you should see your virtual ports
4. Type "change CNCA0 portname=COM255" press Enter (change cnca0 or comxxx as necessary)
5. Open Device Manager and see under "com0com - serial port emulators" with aliases listed (NOT under "Ports COM & LPT")

That should do it!

Comment: But can this be scripted in a .bat file